# Grouping data based on id and time in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am doing a query where I can aggregate the data based on the ID and time. I have successfully aggregate the data based on ID but when I add the time, the query doesn't recognize the time column.

Sample code:

```
SELECT
DATE(Request_Timestamp) as Date,
     ID, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'EN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lang_EN,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'SN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lang_SN,

 FROM (
   SELECT 
    DATE(Request_Timestamp),
     ID, 
      CASE 
        WHEN Language in ('EN', 'English') THEN 'EN' 
        WHEN Language in ('MY', 'Malay')  THEN 'MY' ELSE Language 
      END AS Language,
     
   FROM table
   GROUP BY   ID, Language, DATE(Request_Timestamp)
 )
 GROUP BY  ID, DATE(Request_Timestamp)
)
```

Sample input:

[image]

Sample output

[image]

Error(after SELECT):

```
Unrecognized name: Request_Timestamp at [9:6]
```

Updated: it works with Request_Timestamp but not DATE(Request_Timestamp)

Comment: the field name is Timestamp or Request_Timestamp  ?

Comment: edited on query. I accidentally removed request word in this post

Comment: check the answer below

Comment: @swm . . . As written, your query cannot return any value other than `0` or `1`, because the subquery removed duplicates by id and day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

```
SELECT
     DATE,
        ..
    
     FROM (
       SELECT 
        DATE(Request_Timestamp)as DATE,
         ID, 
          CASE 
           ..
          END AS Language,
         
       FROM table
       GROUP BY   ID, Language, Request_Timestamp
     ) t
     GROUP BY ID, DATE, Language
```

Answer (score 0):

alias name was missed and extra , was there i removed

```
SELECT
DATE(Timestamp),
     ID, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'EN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lang_EN,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Language = 'SN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lange_SN

 FROM                
   FROM table
 GROUP BY  ID, DATE(Timestamp)
```

Comment: i need to use the inner statement . so remove it will affect my query

Answer (score 0):

You seem to just want conditional aggregation.  Because you just want to count matching boolean conditions, use `COUNTIF()`:

```
SELECT DATE(Request_Timestamp) as Date, ID, 
       COUNTIF(Language in ('EN', 'English')) AS lang_EN,
       COUNTIF(Language in ('MY', 'Malay')) AS lang_MY
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE, ID;
```